# CSS docking within DIV

Tags: html, css, layout

I have some HTML that currently looks like this (in a few different pages; and one page is going to have multiple of these):

```
<div class="view"></div>
```

Via JavaScript, this will be programmatically populated at runtime with content similar to this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="button1">...</div>
        <div class="button2">...</div>
        <div class="button3">...</div>
    </div>
```

The "view" div will have a size defined according to the containing page (it may be a fixed px width/height, or it may be a percentage width/height, it depends on the specific page).  But its size is not allowed to be influenced by its content.

The three button divs should appear at the bottom of the containing div (note: not the page or window!) with a fixed height and evenly spreading the width (ie. three equal columns).

The content div should consume all remaining space in the container div -- again, its size should not be influenced by its own content.

Note that the actual size of the "view" div is not known at the time the CSS rules are being written, so "content" cannot express its size in pixels.

How do I express this in CSS?  Thus far my attempts have managed to satisfy one or the other of these constraints but not all at once.  Note that the primary target is Chrome 17 (or actually a Webkit browser equivalent to that), which means that I can use a little CSS3 but not some of the nicer box stuff.  I don't have to worry about it working in old-IE, but otherwise multi-browser support would be nice.

(I can restructure the divs inside "container" if required to make things work, including adding sub-parents, but both "view" and "container" itself need to be like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much fumbling around I think I've found the magic.  Not sure if this can be improved further.

HTML:

```
<div class="view" style="width: 960px; height: 180px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="button1">...</div>
        <div class="button2">...</div>
        <div class="button3">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

content
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 5ex);
}

button1, button2, button3
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 5ex;
}
```

(Note that I haven't tested large content yet; I suspect I'll probably have to add `overflow: hidden` or something too.)

One minor annoyance is that it doesn't seem feasible to add margins to these elements, because then they break out of the correct positioning.  I suppose it might be possible to do some more `calc` magic to account for the margins but it's probably easier to use an internal div to draw borders instead.